# How to use Promises in Postman tests?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, promise, postman

I need to use some async code in my Postman test.

As it's a complex scenario I've reproduced the scenario in a very simple test with the following code:

```
let promiseNumber = 0;

function resolvedPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pm.sendRequest('https://postman-echo.com/get', (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject();
            } else {
                console.log(`Resolved promise ${++promiseNumber}`);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

resolvedPromise()
    .then(resolvedPromise)
    .then(resolvedPromise)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The expected result on the console would be:

```
Resolved promise 1
Resolved promise 2
Resolved promise 3
```

But instead I receive:

```
Resolved promise 1
```

Is there a way to make Promises or async code available at Postman?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATES 27th Feb, 2023**:

- The solution below has been tested in versions from Postman 5.x.x to 10.10.9 and it works as expected.
- As of Postman v10.6.0 Promises and async-await are fully supported and the workaround below is not needed anymore. Technical details: [Postman App PR 4131](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4131) [Postman Sandbox PR 872](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-sandbox/pull/872)

### Original Solution (Postman < 10.6)

**UPDATE**: The original solution used `2147483647` as timeout value. A user suggested using `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in the comments. For me, both worked, but many users reported `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` does not work so the code uses the specific number `2147483647`.

I realized that it always stops working after I use pm.sendRequest. If I try to resolve the Promise it works.

It seems a known bug looking at [this thread](https://community.getpostman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636).

The workaround for it would be only leave an open timeout while processing the code. Just ensure all possible paths clear the timeout or the call will hang for 300000 years

```
// This timeout ensures that Postman will not close the connection before completing async tasks.
//  - it must be cleared once all tasks are completed or it will hang
const interval = setTimeout(() => {}, 2147483647);

let promiseNumber = 0;

function resolvedPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pm.sendRequest('https://postman-echo.com/get', (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject();
            } else {
                console.log(`Resolved promise ${++promiseNumber}`);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

resolvedPromise()
    .then(resolvedPromise)
    .then(resolvedPromise)
    .then(() => clearTimeout(interval))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        clearTimeout(interval);
    });
```

You can check that the promises are resolved by checking the Postman Console (View -> Show Postman Console):

```
Resolved promise 1
Resolved promise 2
Resolved promise 3
```

Comment: Personally, I woudl use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` instead of hardcoded `2147483647`. It's not the same number but it is the _maximum safe integer_.

Comment: I tried to use it with Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and it didn't work. If you replace it with anything over 1000 it works.

Comment: Each request seems to take somewhere between 200 and 500 ms.
So yes, I can confirm the previous comment suggesting _anything over 1000_.
The more requests you chain, the higher value you will need for the
`clearTimeout`.
I also played with the upper limit, and found that 1 billion works, but not
10 billion (ms).

Comment: @seemcat Agree, this is very important! Do NOT use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`!! Use something like `100000`.

Comment: I am confirming that Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER does not work on PM (V7.36.7 the last version which plays nice with our corporate firewall). Since the goal is block until the script is done, I choose a meaningful interval, such as // keeps sandbox alive!! const sandbox_stay_alive = setTimeout(() => {}, 60 * 1000);

Comment: Thank you @AndrewDennison, I have updated it mentioning your experience.

Comment: wow I can't believe Promises were not supported just as I was thinking it would solve my own prerequest scripting needs. @AndrewDennison however reasonable you think a timeout should last to run the script it would be a good idea to wrap it in a `try catch` block and throw a `request timeout` error to the console

Comment: FYI to everyone looking this thread. At this time it seems like Postman may not support `setTimeout()`, Promises, `async` `await`. However, it seems like at least `setTimeout()` was supported in the past.

Without the ability to chain promises and async operations together it is hard to develop meaningful scripts in my opinion: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11063#issuecomment-1441005273

Comment: @stelloprint I have just checked on Postman 10.10.9 and the solution above still works as expected. Also since Postman 10.6.0 it fully supports promises and async-await https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-sandbox/pull/872 and has for a long time kept setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Felipe's answer, I'd like to share a little bit more with my experience in using Postman.

As I need to extract some values from the responses of `pm.sendRequest` and use them in making the main call (e.g. query string) and/or in the **Tests** section, I run the script in the **Pre-request Script** section and set the values in Postman environment variables.

One important point that I find out is that I must put all the code of setting variables (e.g. `pm.environment.set(k, v)`) before `clearTimeout(timeout)`. Otherwise, if I do it the other way round, the `pm.environment.set(k, v)` code will still be run but the value of the environment variable will not be updated.

---

Below is an example with Postman `v8.5.1`.

##### Main call

Expect to get `TEST` from the environment variables.

```
GET http://google.com/{{TEST}}
```

##### Pre-request Script

Expect to set the `TEST` environment variable of which the value comes from the results of multiple APIs. In this example, I just use the last value returned from `Promise.all`.

```js
// make sure you do NOT use Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER !!
const timeout = setTimeout(() => {}, 100000);

const promise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Calling');
        pm.sendRequest('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + _.random(1, 100), (err, res) => {
            console.log('run');
            if (err) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve(res.json());
            }
        });
    });
}

Promise.all([
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
    promise(),
]).then(values => {
    console.log('All done');
    const exampleValue = values[values.length-1].id;
    console.log("Last ID: " + exampleValue);

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // move this line before clearTimeout to fix TEST being undefined
    pm.environment.set("TEST", exampleValue);
});
```

##### Tests

Expect to print the `TEST` environment variable.

```js
// you get undefined if pm.environment.set is run after clearTimeout
// you get correct value if pm.environment.set is run before clearTimeout
console.log(pm.variables.get("TEST"));
```

##### How to test

After copying the URL and all the scripts to Postman, open up **Console** and click **Send**. Take a look at the query string of the actual URL being called (i.e. `GET http://google.com/%7B%7BTEST%7D%7D`). Then rearrange the code as mentioned in the comments and click **Send** again. This time everything should work as expected.

Comment: Hi! I just found myself in a scenario exactly like this one. Tried implementing this solution and even though it works when running from Postman, it doesn't when I execute the tests with newman. My variable (setting it as global, collection, environment or just variable) doesn't get set... Any idea if it could have something to do with Postman version? I am in 9.0.3 (latest)