# Postman - Populating objects and array from secondary requests in Tests

Tags: javascript, postman

I am trying to understand how pm.sendRequest works.

I have a query and some Tests code that loops through a response and makes a second request using pm.sendRequest with variables from the initial response.

This works, but within the pm.sendRequest I have a loop that creates an array that I need to push into a global array (defined before pm.sendRequest is called).

The problem is the pushing doesn’t work. I end up with an empty array.

So my question is: are variables that are supposed to be global (to the code, not Postman global variables) not available inside pm.sendRequest?

Code sample:

```
let myArray = [];

pm.sendRequest( url, function (err, response){

      let foo = [];   
      //a for loop here that push populates foo[] just fine
      for {
          foo.push(name);
      } //end loop

      console.info(foo); //all good

      myArray.push(foo);
      console.info(myArray) //all good
 });

console.info(myArray); //empty
```

foo array is properly populated at the end, but my Array is empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching on this, I found that the pm.sendRequest method is an asynchronous request: [https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20pm.sendRequest%20method%20to%20send%20a%20request%20asynchronously%20from%20a%20Pre%2Drequest%20or%20Test%20script](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20pm.sendRequest%20method%20to%20send%20a%20request%20asynchronously%20from%20a%20Pre%2Drequest%20or%20Test%20script).

That means it's not a blocking request and it runs in the background, independently of the code that follows it.

As such, the last `console.log`. output does not wait for the `pm.sendRequest` function to complete and populate the array.

Some workarounds for this are possible, using global variables and promises:

https://community.postman.com/t/can-i-use-pm-sendrequest-to-send-requests-synchronously/225/14

https://james.jacobson.app/javascript-promises-and-postmans-sendrequest/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934401/10792097

However, overall, it looks like this is not the way to go about it in the Postman universe.

I think we're supposed to split out each request by itself and use request workflows: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/

This is what I'll be trying to do next.